# Capture 802.11 packets on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberrypi

I would like to capture 802.11 packets on Raspberry pi 3. I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.1.19-v7+ armv7l) on my Pi.

I have tried Airmmon-ng and iw to create a new interface on monitor mode. I tried using tcpdump, wireshark and tshark. They didnt work out.

My project involves analyzing the back off factor of the tx_packets and some timing characteristics of packets.  It would be of great help if i could get some help on other tools that are currently available for Raspberry pi 3 for capturing the timestamps of the 802.11 packets.